# Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call,antd,React

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want use antd in Reactjs,and I have try import a button,the code as follows,however,I come across a mistake.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1>hello world</h1>
     <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the error message is :

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1465)
    at Object.useContext (react.development.js:1473)
    at InternalButton (button.js:137)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451)
```

```
The above error occurred in the <Button> component:

    at InternalButton (http://localhost:3000/main.5d9d2a7ccfedfebc8c0f.hot-update.js:2316:30)
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

I have check the link **https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html**,and I checked **the version of react-dom,and the grammer of Hooks**,but I still can't solve the problem!

Comment: Which versions of `react` and `antd` packages are you using (defined in your `package.json`) ?